# Getting version number with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like:

```
"MyProgramm build version 0.0.7.161"
```

I want to get the version from it. I tried:

```
String(build_num[/MyProgramm build version (\d*.\d*.\d*.\d*)$/, 1])
```

and I get:

```
", 0.0.7.161"
```

Why do I get the comma at the front?

Comment: I don't think this is your issue, but `.` is a special character meaning any character..try escaping it `\.`

Comment: You don’t need to call `String` global method explicitly either. `puts build_num[/MyProgramm build version (\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)$/, 1]` works for me pretty fine, giving `=> "0.0.7.161"` as expected.

Comment: @Sam i did this one '(\.\d*.\d*.\d*.\d*$)/', after that i got only  **,** **,**

Comment: @BilowYuriy: I cannot recreate your problem given the info you provided. Could you post a sequence of statements we can past into `irb` in order to understand your problem in detail? As for @mudasobwa this seems to work for me if I use `build_num = "MyProgramm build version 0.0.7.161"`

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. I get `"0.0.7.161"`.

Comment: @sawa It is fine, but honestly i don't know what letters is before <MyProgramm> can i by expression somewhat exclude them at all.It seems to me that they spoil my expression with comma

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something simple like:

```
str = "MyProgramm build version 0.0.7.161"
str.scan(/\d+/).join('.') # => "0.0.7.161"
```

That's fine if you know the only numbers in the string are in the version substring. But, what happens if the name of the app has a number in it?

```
str = "HTML2PDF build version 0.0.7.161"
str.scan(/\d+/).join('.') # => "2.0.0.7.161"
```

or worse:

```
str = "foobar_v1.0 build version 1.0.7.161"
str.scan(/\d+/).join('.') # => "1.0.1.0.7.161"
```

Obviously that's not what you want, so, at that point the code has to get smarter. If the version substring is always at the end of the string, then something like this will work:

```
str = "HTML2PDF build version 0.0.7.161"
str.split.last.scan(/\d+/).join('.') # => "0.0.7.161"
```

But, now that you have the substring, what are you going to do with it? Compare it to something? You can't compare this sort of string to get an idea of one version being less than another:

```
"0.0.7.161" < "0.0.7.2" # => true
```

Comparing characters isn't the same as comparing integers so there needs to be more intelligence, or at least something to make sure the strings are going to sort/compare in the desired order:

```
str.split.last.scan(/\d+/).map{ |s| '%03d' % s.to_i }.join('.') # => "000.000.007.161"
"000.000.007.161" < "000.000.007.002" # => false
```

Or conversely:

```
"000.000.007.002" < "000.000.007.161" # => true
```

Version number comparison is a problem, and you'll find various ways people have tried to deal with it out there. The couple of times I've needed to do it I fall back on using the code in Ruby's [Gem::Version](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html) class, which helps. Still, you'll run into weirdness now and then and have to figure out what works for your situation.

Comment: Yep.Thank you!! I got my version number

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to do this using the scan method like so:

```
[20] pry(main)> string
=> "MyProgramm build version 0.0.7.161"
[21] pry(main)> string.scan(/\d\.*/).join
=> "0.0.7.161"
```

so try

```
state.scan(/\d\.*/).join
```

Comment: There are problems, Anthony.  This may help you correct them: `"007..161".scan(/\d./).join #=> "007.16" #=> "007.16"
`. To avoid possible downvotes, I suggest you delete your answer, work on it (including thorough testing), then undelete.

Comment: Thanks Cary - I think I copied over the wrong RegEx initially.  Your post includes that initial submission but I have since edited it.  If you still think it's best I resubmit, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: @Anthony Thank you for your expression, but i still got comma. By the way, honestly i don't know what letters is before <MyProgramm> can i by expression somewhat exclude them at all.It seems to me that they spoil my expression with comma

Comment: This has problems with any string containing a digit followed by a period, which could be found with an app named something like `foo2.rb`.

Comment: Hi @BilowYuriy not a problem.  Do you know if the last part of the string will always be the version #?  If so, can you just grab the last 15-20 characters and then run my expression on it?

Comment: Try it with the string "007..161".  It should return `nil`, meaning no match, but it doesn't.  One problem is the `*` following `.`.  It permits zero matches, which is wrong.  You want exactly one match.  Also `\d` permits only single digit numbers.  Test, test, test!  See @theTinMan's answer.

Comment: I learned a lot from you post @theTinMan - I can't argue with your comment, you're right.  I merely did the simplest thing that worked with the string provided.

Comment: Well, that's how we start, but experience, i.e., slamming into walls, teaches us it's not that straightforward, at least not usually, especially with version numbers. They can be evil.